# Android - uninstall other system app as system app

Tags: android, kotlin, android-source, android-package-managers

My app is running as a system app on a custom AOSP image. I am able to uninstall/install other APKs that I'm downloading from my backend. However, I cannot uninstall other system apps (which is a hard requirement for my purpose). My current mechanism is to use the deletePackage mechanism from the Android package manager via reflection:

```
val cPackageManager = Class.forName("android.content.pm.PackageManager")
cPackageDeleteObserver = Class.forName("android.content.pm.IPackageDeleteObserver")
deletePackage = cPackageManager.getMethod("deletePackage", String::class.java, cPackageDeleteObserver, Integer.TYPE)
deletePackage!!.invoke(context.packageManager, packageName, deleteObserver, DELETE_ALL_USERS)
```

Does anybody know how to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't you need to be a rooted device to uninstall `System apps`, or have you found a way to do this without any rooting?
2. You must `remount` the system, since you run SELinux, to be able to rearrange the locked files in the system.

3.You can run this code in your app instead

```
try{
 Process su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
 DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(su.getOutputStream());

 outputStream.writeBytes("pm uninstall com.package.name");
 outputStream.flush();
 outputStream.writeBytes("exit\n");
 outputStream.flush();
 su.waitFor();
}catch(IOException e){
 throw new Exception(e);
}catch(InterruptedException e){
 throw new Exception(e);
}
```

if `pm uninstall` doesn't work, use the `rm -rf path/deletefolder` then reboot the system

Comment: the device in question is not rooted, so this will probably not work. My app has system privileges though, but I guess it won't be able without remounting the system as you said.

Comment: If you still have time to develop then try this here, `mount -o rw,remount /system `, Method 2. By terminal you should runt the code above.  Try this locally before further development --> https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/110927/how-to-mount-system-rewritable-or-read-only-rw-ro

Comment: What Android version are you running/targeting?

Comment: I'll look into that - thanks for your help. I'm targeting 8.1

Comment: This should work in Oreo in my experience. I did `mount -o rw,remount /system` all the time